Where is this NPC's voice coming from?
At around this location here (zoomed in)

there is an NPC's voice that starts talking to you within a certain radius.
You can see it more clearly in this image:

He (assuming gender based on voice) says things such as,

I'm not that ugly, am I?


Oi! You there!


Stop pretending you can't see me!

Where is he? Why can't I find him, no matter where I look within earshot?

Just a quick tip about those game screenshots you shared. Consider using JPG or WebP formats instead of PNG. These formats offer smaller file sizes, resulting in faster image loading. PNGs tend to load slower, especially for higher-resolution images.

Welcome to Elden Ring. Have fun with quests that are (sometimes) designed to be obtuse.

The reason you can't see him is because he is disguised as a tree. You have to hit the tree to break the spell and reveal the NPC. Here's what the tree in question look (I said tree but it's practically bush sized).


Try rolling into the tree instead of attacking. I don't know if there's risk of killing/aggroing him, but generally speaking it's the safer option. Same with Laurentius in Dark Souls.

If I remember correctly, the correct bush is a slightly different colour than the others, I think it's a bit lighter, but it's been a while since I saw it.

@UnownK do you know what tree it is? Or do I just roll into all of them?

@Daemons Edited the post with a picture, I said tree but it's pretty much human sized.

@UnownK I saw, just accepted your answer.
